# reporting statements: that-clauses

Tags: negation, homework, comma-splices

How would you write the negative statement of:

> She declared the item to be faulty, the police reported the girl to be missing.

Would it be:

> She declared the item not to be faulty, the police reported the girl not to be missing.

or

> She declared the item to be not faulty, the police reported the girl to be not missing.

or

> She declared the item to not be faulty, the police reported the girl to not be missing.

Comment: This question would appear to be off-topic because it is an appeal for contributors to (2) answer homework questions and (1) sort out what OP should have copied down _as_ those questions.

Comment: @Janus: Oops! Comment deleted, and thanks for flagging it up.

Comment: this question does not answer a homework question. In the book "advanced grammar in use" edited by Cambridge, Unit 33 paragraph B page 66, the lesson gives examples of reporting statements using verbs such as acknowledge, assume believe consider...only in affirmative form but not in negative form.

Answer (score 2):

This looks suspiciously like a badly written homework or test question.

I am going to guess that what the authority who posed the question wants is for you to negate the complement clauses:

> ... the item to be faulty.
>   ... the girl to be not missing.

Your attempts are good guesses, and would certainly be understood. But ordinarily *declare*, *report*, *judge* and similar verbs take infinitive clauses only when these are positive. When the clause is negative the infinitive construction is felt to be awkward. You will do better to 'translate' the infinitive clause into the corresponding *that* clause with a finite verb:

> She declared **that** the item **was not** faulty.
>   The police reported **that** the girl **was not** missing.

I say the question is badly written because it is also leaves open the possibility of negating the head clauses:

> She declared ...
>   The police reported ...

These may be negated with *not* and *do-*support:

> She did not declare the item to be faulty.
>   The police did not report the girl to be missing.

Comment: I can go with this. We seem to be getting a lot of questions lately that revolve around "unhelpful" choices presented by "linguistically challenged" test setters. It seems to me the only way you can "elegantly" use the infinitive in such contexts is if "Not Faulty" and "Not Missing" are considered as "autonomous" categorisations - for example, elements in a drop-down list, or the text associated with specific checkboxes on a form.

Comment: @Fumble, or in a case such as “The jury found the defendent to be not guilty”, though here of course ‘to be’ would more likely be deleted. I would say, though, that there are certain other contexts where an infinitive clause in the negative is not awkward: “She declared it to be not quite what she needed/expected/wanted” is perfectly fine to my ear, for example.

Comment: @Janus: Good examples. I think one way to establish whether **declare to be not X** is likely to be acceptable is to ask whether you'd think it really odd to transcribe the declared state using italics or quote marks (or in speech, use exaggerated stress or hold up your hands and wiggle both index fingers! :)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'd think of the *not* in *not quite what she wanted* as negating merely the adverb, not the clause, and I think that makes a difference. And *not guilty* is of course a fixed attributive phrase in legal contexts.

Comment: Yes, I agree on both counts—but in the second of the asker's options, _not_ only negates the predicate as well.